# ajax post not working php mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a table in which i can add rows using javascript. I have a select box in each row. I am calling onchange for select box. It works only for first row,not working for the rows added through javascript. Please help.

This is the html table with add and delete row button:

```
<INPUT type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('payment_table')" />
<INPUT class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('payment_table')" />

<TABLE  class="table table-hover dataTable table-striped width-full" data-plugin="dataTable" id="payment_table">
    <TR>
        <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>
        <TD>
            <SELECT name="product" class="form-control product" id="product" >
                <option value="">Select Product</option>
                <?php
                $sql="select products_name,products_amount,products_tmp_id from slv_products where products_status <> '0'";
                $results = $connect->runQuery($sql);
                foreach($results as $result) {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $result['products_tmp_id']; ?>"><?php echo $result['products_name']; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </SELECT>
        </TD>
        <TD><input class="form-control col-sm-2" type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" placeholder="Quantity"></TD>
        <TD><input class="form-control" type="text" name="amount" id="amount" placeholder="Amount" readonly></TD>
    </TR>

</TABLE>
```

This is the script to add and delete row and ajax :

```
    function addRow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
            //alert(newcell.childNodes);
            switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                case "text":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                        break;
                case "checkbox":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                        break;
                case "select-one":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                        break;
            }
        }
    }

    function deleteRow(tableID) {
        try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;

        for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                if(rowCount <= 1) {
                    alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                    break;
                }
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
            }


        }
        }catch(e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }

   $(document).ready(function() {

  $('.product').change(function() {    
var id = $(this).val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.php",
    data: {
        id : id
    },
    success: function(data) {
     if(data){

   $("#amount").val(data);
    $("#quantity").val("1");   
    } 
    },
     error : function(data){
  alert("Error occured !!");
  }
});    
}); 

  });
```

This is ajax.php :

```
<?php
include('/opt/lampp/htdocs/slv/includes/config.php');
$id = $_POST['id'];
$query = "SELECT products_amount FROM slv_products WHERE products_tmp_id='$id'"; //expecting one row
$results = $connect->runQuery($query);
foreach($results as $result){
    echo $result['products_amount'];
}
?>
```

Comment: where's the mysql for this then? how do we know that isn't failing (also)?

Comment: where is your `ajax.php` ??

Comment: Change your .ajax error to be like this so you can see more about the error: error: function (request, status, error) { alert('Error: ' + error); }

Comment: @Fred-ii- and devpro. added ajax.php please check

Comment: chk console for error and response., also `console.log(id);` r u getting id before ajax request? check `print_r($_POST)` getting values or not in php and i am not sure about the path, is it fine? `/opt/lampp/htdocs/slv/includes/config.php`

Comment: POST doesnt work for the row i add after clicking the `Add Row` button

Comment: If POST doesn't work, error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and as stated, look at your developer console, including looking at what the HTML source is and a var_dump(). Check for errors on the query also.

Comment: what r u getting in `console.log(id);` use it after this line `var id = $(this).val();` and chk browser console

Comment: `console.log(id)` shows only the value from first row onchange value. Else for other rows its not showing anything

Comment: than try with `var id = $("#product").val();` instead of `var id = $(this).val();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ajax code should be like this:

```
    $('body').on('change', '.product', function() { 
      var _that = $(this);   
      var id = _that.val();

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: {
           id : id
        },
        success: function(data) {
          if(data){
            _that.parents("tr").find(".amount").val(data);
            _that.parents("tr").find(".quantity").val("1");   
          } 
       },
       error : function(data){
         alert("Error occured !!");
       }
     });    
   });
```

It's because of binding of html element. If html is added dynamic then you can't bind it with jQuery directly.

Comment: It almost worked. but value reflecting only in the first row.

Comment: I could post values from second row as well but values not getting displayed for the respective rows

Comment: @varuni: did u mean, only ist <option> is working not others?

Comment: No all the options are working. But `$("#amount").val(data);` and  `$("#quantity").val("1");` is not working for all the rows. if i change value in the second row value is getting displayed in the first row.

Comment: its because you are using `id` so it get conflicted there could be only one `id` for a line.. use `class` instead, check updated answer.

Comment: @SonuBamniya - you would need to fetch the parent row `$(this).parents("tr");` It won't be able to find an element with `.amount` inside a `select`...